# Java Script INFINITY property

Tags: javascript, math.js

I see `var r = INFINITY;` in [v8/math.js](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/cd81dd6d740ff82a1abbc68615e8769bd467f91e/src/js/math.js#L77-L102)

But it doesn't work in the console.

What is the source of INFINITY property?

How is it implemented internally?

Comment: Isn't it a CONST reference to [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity) (`Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY`)?

Comment: What is the source? And how is it implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely a reference defined inside that codebase to refer to positive infinity. Positive and negative infinity are features of the IEEE 754 double precision floating point standard used in JavaScript.

**Implementation**

```
Sign Exponent Fraction 
0    11⋯11    00⋯00     +Infinity   
1    11⋯11    00⋯00     -Infinity
```

[Source](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html)

**Source**

I can see an `INFINITY` macro in that codebase [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/2fc2cb99f52974d0743610189213a94585c30ac6/src/js/macros.py#L173). But it is in Python. How it makes its way into JavaScript might be part of the build.

Comment: What is the source? And how is it implemented?

Comment: Very interesting link, an upvote from me. Didn't know Python allows `1/0`.

Comment: Yes. Never see anything like this in another language. (1/0). You have any more information about this construct?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like their CONST reference (for readability) to [Infinity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity) (`Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY`).

> What is the source? And how is it implemented?

It's a part of the JS runtime, and may or may not differntiate across different browsers. The implementation would be a Number that is greater than any other number:

```
Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER // true
Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY > Number.MAX_VALUE        // true
Infinity + Infinity    // Infinity
Infinity - Infinity    // NaN, interesting
```

---

The following is from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/POSITIVE_INFINITY:

This value behaves slightly differently than mathematical infinity:

- Any positive value, including POSITIVE_INFINITY, multiplied by POSITIVE_INFINITY is POSITIVE_INFINITY.
- Any negative value, including NEGATIVE_INFINITY, multiplied by POSITIVE_INFINITY is NEGATIVE_INFINITY.
- Zero multiplied by POSITIVE_INFINITY is NaN.
- NaN multiplied by POSITIVE_INFINITY is NaN.
- POSITIVE_INFINITY, divided by any negative value except NEGATIVE_INFINITY, is NEGATIVE_INFINITY.
- POSITIVE_INFINITY, divided by any positive value except POSITIVE_INFINITY, is POSITIVE_INFINITY.
- POSITIVE_INFINITY, divided by either NEGATIVE_INFINITY or POSITIVE_INFINITY, is NaN.
- Any number divided by POSITIVE_INFINITY is Zero.

That looks like pretty much the whole implementation, shouldn't be too hard to write that as code.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the infinity is wired to the core code to behave like this.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes. seems like converting those lines into code is pretty much the whole Infinity object.

Answer (score 1):

`INFINITY` looks like is `Infinity`:

```
utils.InstallConstants(global, [
  // ECMA 262 - 15.1.1.1.
  "NaN", NaN,
  // ECMA-262 - 15.1.1.2.
  "Infinity", INFINITY,
  // ECMA-262 - 15.1.1.2.
  "undefined", UNDEFINED,
]);
```

[Source](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/ed600e5556bd3f668a427e7051ab66821c8558e1/src/js/v8natives.js#L129-L136)

As to why it's not available from the console, it's probably because it's run under a different scope (i.e. different from window). My best guess would be that the `global` object is the global object, which is why you can use `INFINITY` like that (instead of `global.INFINITY` which should be the same).

Comment: Not sure scope is the correct term here. This code is evaluated inside the runtime and is not user-land.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the infinity is wired to the core code to behave like this

Answer (score 0):

This is a [CONSTANT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) reference to `Infinity`

From [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity):

> [The] Infinity property is a numeric value representing infinity.

It behaves like infinity, i.e. any positive number multiplied by `Infinity` is `Infinity`, and anything divided by `Infinity` is `0`.

```
console.log(1 * Infinity); // Infinity
console.log(1 / Infinity); // 0
```

Comment: What is the source? And how is it implemented?